# Selenium Test Suite: differing paths to test cases

Tags: testing, path, selenium, suite

I have a test suite that does the following

1. log in
2. do tests
3. log out

since I want to reuse log in and log out with other test suites I moved them into a separate folder and referenced those test cases in the href field e.g.

a href="..\lib\fLogIn.html"

Selenium however raises an exception that it can't find the file in question.
I tried all sorts of URLs, e.g.

file:///E:\absolute\path\lib\fLogIn.html

file:///E:/absolute/path/lib/fLogIn.html

../lib/fLogIn.html

..//lib//fLogIn.html

..\lib\fLogIn.html

etc.

I even tried to access them through a webserver.. no success.

Does anyone have an idea as to how this can be solved?

I really want to reuse test cases.

Thanks a lot

Juergen

PS: forgot to add: I am using Windows OS

Answer (score 0):

Try to move all the reusable functions to an upper level class and using them accordingly.

Comment: Hi Javabeginner, what we are now doing is to put all test suites in one folder and all test cases in subfolders of which. This is not very elegant but it does the trick. Did you mean that?